# How to pre-digitize a video? Or how to apply anti-aliasing to a video file?

Tags: matlab, video, video-streaming, computer-vision

How to pre-digitize a video? Or how to apply anti-aliasing to a video file? I am getting some blur frames, when I try to analyze the video in MATLAB.

Answer (score 0):

Your video is already digitised. So, nothing to be done here.

And the blur you get is on almost all the videos you can ever see. The problem (or the good fact) is that when watching a video playing, the human eye does not see the blur. However, when stopping on a frame, you can see it.

In computer vision, there are more approaches to solve the blur problem:

- Ignore it. Hope it is not too much to corrupt your image
- Buy a proffesional camera, made for computer vision. It can reduce most blur, even in extremely demanding situations. It is not cheap.
- Correct it using superpixel algorithms.
- Build your algorithms around a method that is insensitive to blur (phase correlation, by example).